# strip an list as like a string

Tags: python, string, list

If the output of a code is in the format

```
output = [['good'], ['man']]
```

and I need only 'good man', so I do

```
str(output).strip('],'[')
```

but it gives

```
good'], ['man
```

Can someone help?

Comment: Why strip? Why not *join* the strings with `' '.join([nested[0] for nested in output])`? And how did you end up with nested lists in the first place?

Comment: `" ".join(map(" ".join, output))` which will work for sublists with more than one word

Comment: Yes it works, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of working around with `strip`, I'd use a list comprehension to convert the input from a list of single itemed lists to a list of strings, and then just `join` it:

```
>>> l = [['good'], ['man']]
>>> result = ' '.join([x[0] for x in l])
>>> result
'good man'
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do i with something, that is not so elegant but should work like:

```
templist = output.split(',') 

st = "" 

for each element in templist: 
    st+=element(2:-2)
    st+=" "


#if its important to you not to have one space at the end you can take it of here
return st
```